# Flutter: update TabController length dynamically

Tags: flutter, dart

```
@override
void initState() {
    _portfoliosTabController = TabController(
      vsync: this,
      length: Provider.of<MyRents>(context, listen: false).list.length,
    );
}
```

That length changes dynamically depending on many factors and functions and it is given by `Provider`. How can I update it without moving it inside the `build()` (that creates other issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Every length is changed you should create a new TabController then you have to update the UI every your TabController have new instance
2. Save the last of index selected to the Variable and Every create new tabController set initialIndex based on last of index selected

Comment: if I create a new tabController as I was doing during the build, the index changes every time to 0

Comment: Save the last of index selected to the Variable and Every create new tabController set initialIndex based on last of index selected

Comment: with initialIndex works fine. Add that to your answer and I'll approve it